# How Django handle multiple requests send at the same time

Tags: django, multithreading

I have checked most of the comments and the answer always was that Django (on local machine) handles only **one request at a time**. I have simple django application with view function that waits 5 seconds. When I run two the same GET requests in postman, I can see both requests are handled in the same time, they are not queued or overwritten one by another. My question is how it is possible?

My view code:

```
def wait_some_time(request):

    import time
    print("Printed immediately.")
    time.sleep(5)
    print("Printed after 5 seconds.")

    return Response({'message': 'nothing'})
```

Postman request:
[Postman request (I'm sending 2 requests in the same time)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VaCvl.png)

Console output:

```
Printed immediately.
Printed immediately.
Printed after 5 seconds.
[05/Jan/2022 14:55:35] "GET /api/user/test HTTP/1.1" 200 21
Printed after 5 seconds.
[05/Jan/2022 14:55:36] "GET /api/user/test HTTP/1.1" 200 21
```

Comment: Where did you get the idea that the dev server only handles one request at a time? It's multithreaded by default https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-runserver-nothreading

Comment: From this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49214051/6579746
You are completly right, thanks for your answer, I couldn't find information about that.

`The server is multithreaded by default.`

Comment: hi, i'm not sure what you are trying to achieve but it seems that you may not be testing what you are looking for correctly. Each request is handled separately  and so the output you are getting is correct for 2 separate requests, each request will print immediately and after 5 seconds.   Could you explain what it is you're actually trying to achieve?

Comment: @caleo
I was wondering if django uses only one thread, but results and IainShelvington comment prove it launches other threads if needed.